# ToChar() for multiple characters?

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding

I need to search and convert a string of characters such as 3F20.

[Convert.ToChar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f3ew98y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) only takes a single character code as input.

Is there another function that takes several characters instead?

Thank you.

Comment: Is 3F20 a string i.e. "3F20" or an array of bytes {3F, 20} that you are trying to convert to string?

Comment: It's an array of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a ToCharArray method for this.

Please see the example here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to choose how to interpret the bytes.

```
    Dim b() As Byte = {&H3F, &H20, &H35, &H41}
    Dim s As String

    'encoding of choice
    Dim enc As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)

    s = enc.GetChars(b)
    Debug.WriteLine(s)
```